# Stencil not working with a 500 server error

Tags: bigcommerce

Using stencil 3.0.3, node 12.21 cornerstone theme was working and suddenly stopped with a weird server error:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    Error: The BigCommerce server responded with a 500 error
    at Object.internals.getResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/plugins/renderer/renderer.module.js:128:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async internals.implementation (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/plugins/renderer/renderer.module.js:39:20)
    at async module.exports.internals.Manager.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/toolkit.js:45:28)
    at async Object.internals.handler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/handler.js:46:20)
    at async exports.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/handler.js:31:20)
    at async Request._lifecycle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/request.js:312:32)
    at async Request._execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/request.js:221:9)
```

I have tried to re-install big commerce stencil, clean build and still get the same error.... at this point I have no idea what could be causing this issue.

Importantly, there was no code changes in between the day where everything was working and the day where it stopped.

Comment: Hi @yoann, thanks for joining the big commerce developer slack, looks like you're getting some action there about this question! We can update this question with a resolution if one is mentioned in the slack group (and if nobody contributes on this post before then)! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CloudFlare for a CDN? I've ran into this issue and have had to edit my hosts file

I add the following 3 lines.

The first one is for the Store Domain, i.e. if you have MyShoeStore.com

The second 2 contain the auto-generated store-hash for a BigCommerce store that should be visible in your URL bar if you are on the BigCommerce control panel (Logged into the admin view - that's the easiest way to get it, there are some others)

```
35.186.223.98 mystoredomain.com
35.186.223.98 store-abcdefg[store-hash].mybigcommerce.com
35.186.223.98 www.store-abcdefg[store-hash].mybigcommerce.com
```

For some reason, Stencil-CLI gets thrown for a loop when trying to connect to a BigCommerce store that is running behind CloudFlare CDN. This has caused `500` errors in the Stencil-CLI, and a failure to render, during local development, but the store is able to be uploaded and hosted in production without a problem.

I'm not sure if this is the actual issue that you had which caused your `500` error, (It can be due to an error in the syntax of one of the HandleBars templates, but usually Stencil-CLI will output an informative error for that reason.)

The other situation I have seen this in is if you are trying to run Cornerstone on a very old BigCommerce store which is still running their old template framework (Blueprint) - in that situation, certain pages will `500`, but others will work.

This may be helpful for others who are running into this.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a proxy tool to capture traffic between stencil and BigCommerce in order to perhaps find more details on this error.

Unfortunately, as soon as I did that, the site worked again...